# Loop through PHP function, display userdata from Mysql - limit to display to 25 items and add next button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, function

I have this PHP function, which I use to display my userdata. If run once it will basicly display a div with the userdata in it.

```
function listings($fornavn, $efternavn, $email, $adresse, $tlf, $postnr, $city, $fodselsdag, $brugerid,$bartype,$idbar)
{

    ?>

    <div class="container">
    <span class="records" id="id-<?php echo $brugerid;?>">

    <div class="customer bidDiv clearfix">

    <?php if ($bartype=='temp_vip') { ?>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <span class="actionSpan" id="<?php echo $brugerid;?>" value="<?php echo $idbar;?>">
                <a class="edit-opt" id="godkend" href="#">GODKEND</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="actionSpan" id="delete-<?php echo $brugerid;?>" value="<?php echo $bartype;?>">
                <a class="delete-opt" id="delete" href="#">Afvis</a>
                </span>
            </li>

    <?php }else{ ?>

            <ul>
            <li>
                <span class="actionSpan" id="delete-<?php echo $brugerid;?>" value="<?php echo $bartype;?>">
                <a class="delete-opt" id="delete" href="#">Slet</a>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="edit-opt" href="editform.php?id=<?php echo $brugerid."&bartype=".$bartype;?>" rel="facebox">Rediger</a>
            </li>

    <?php if ($bartype =='vip'){?>

            <li>
                <a class="print-opt" href="print.php?id=<?php echo $brugerid;?>" rel="facebox">Print</a>
            </li>

    <?php }else{
         // Dont render vip link
    }}?>
            </ul>
            <p class="contact-data">
                <?php echo $email;?><br>
                Tlf.: <?php echo $tlf;?>
            </p>
            <div class="base-data">
                <h4><?php echo ucwords($fornavn)." ".ucwords($efternavn);?></h4>
                <p>Fødselsdag <?php echo $fodselsdag;?></p>
                <address><?php echo ucwords($adresse) ." ". $postnr ." ". ucwords($city);?></address>
            </div>
    </div><!-- end customer -->

        </div>
    </span>
<?php
```

I mostly use this function in a loop, to display all users from my MySQL database, who has a specific relation to something else.

This is all working great. But currently it would pull all results at once. Right now I only have 5 members, so its no problem, but say I get 800 or 2000 members, the list of users would get very long.

So I want to implement some kind of limit on how many users it displays, but still be able to browse through all the users. Many sites use something like pages and split up the results that way. Links like:

```
[1] [2] [3] [Last page>>]
```

I can't figure out how to start doing this? How would I proceed?

Also looked into this Jquery plugin:
http://andersonferminiano.com/jqueryscrollpagination/

But it keeps reloading my PHP file which results in the Loops being restarted, and it simply displays the results over and over again endlessly.

Can someone help me with the logic behind creating this? Or better, point me in a direction where I could use the jquery pluging above - where it only loads the loop one time, and renders the results as I scroll.

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You need some pagination have a look at http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Comment: You're asking about ***pagination***. [Check out this link](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination). First one I saw; didn't bother to read, but just do a google search for "PHP mysql pagination"

Comment: Thanks thats the word for it!  :) I will have a look, with Pagination it might be easier to implement the jquery plugin I posted.

Comment: Apart from Matt's comment, if you get stuck with your pagination and you want to ask a question here, the function you posted is irrelevant, you would need to post the part where your query the database and loop through the results. And I would recommend you start with "normal" pagination and add jquery / javascript stuff later on when you have got it all working.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I will remember the thing with the function - it was mostly to show/explain what I was trying to do. Cheers

Comment: No problem, just trying to help :-)

Comment: this is where pagination is used. Search for a pagination class written in php and use it according to your requirements

Answer (score 2):

Jquery pagination by default will only break-up the given table into several tabs on the page, that is all the data is actually loaded. There are some that let you do an AJAX request to fetch the next page, to work in conjunction with your PHP code.

Ideally, you want to limit the query using LIMIT (number of rows in the result object) and OFFSET (Start from row X ) which will give you number of records starting from your offset row up until the limit, and then use logic on the PHP side to determine the maximum number of pages.

```
  $page = $_POST["page"] * 25; // make sure that page 0 is the starting page or calculate 
  $SQL =  "SomeQueryText LIMIT 25 OFFSET '$page'" ;
  $result = query ($SQL);
```